# why can't we implement two interfaces that have methods with identical signature which one of them has a default implementation in java?

Tags: java, interface, overriding, interface-implementation

Imagine that we have two interfaces which both have method display() with identical signatures. So far so good. Now I define a default implementation for one of them. Now when I want to implement both of them in my class, it gives me a syntax error. Can anyone help me understand the reason?

For example in the code below,

```
interface Show1 {
    default void display() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}

interface Show2 {
    void display();
}

public class Person implements Show1, Show2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.display();
    }
}
```

I thought that it would print hello because we have the default implementation. And since the two methods in the interfaces doesn't have any interference with each other.
But it gives me syntax error. I would be thankful if you help me find the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: In response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78172017/why-cant-we-implement-two-interfaces-that-have-methods-with-identical-signature/78172052#comment137828767_78172052) (but here to avoid unnecessarily pinging Mark): Your code is basically halfway to being a "proper" diamond problem. Fundamentally, I believe this behavior is to prevent ambiguity as much as possible, something Java tends to be quite mindful of. Though that is just my take on it. Also, note that although Java forces you to override the method, the implementation can simply be `Show1.super.display()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because the designers of Java decided that if you have two or more interfaces with the same (or override-equivalent) method signature, and one or more have a default implementation, then you **must** implement it yourself (that is, it behaves as if there is no default method, just an abstract method).

That implementation could simply be the invocation of the default implementation of one of the interfaces.

For example:

```
interface Show1 {
    default void display() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}

interface Show2 {
    void display();
}

public class Person implements Show1, Show2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.display();
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        Show1.super.display();
    }
}
```

This is not something that happened by accident, this is something that was explicitly and intentionally designed and specified, specifically by [8.4.8 Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding of The Java 17 Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any philosophy behind it?

Comment: @JavadZare Probably to mitigate the infamous [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

Comment: @JavadZare That is basically asking for opinion, which is off-topic. You might find information in the following document, but this document precedes the actual implementation, and seems to use syntax that ultimately wasn't used: http://wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/7/71/2011_Goetz_Extension.pdf Basically, to avoid conflicts, or situations where an interface at compile time didn't have a default method, and at runtime has. It also seems that in the presence of default method in one interface, and just abstract in the other, they consider the abstract one to also have a default: abstract.

Comment: But here I don't see any diamond problem. I still haven't found the reason why designers of java have made java behave in this way.

Comment: @JavadZare Well, as I said, that is asking for opinions, and is off-topic.